# Eslint rule/plugin to merge es6 imports from same module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, import

I would like to merge all my es6 imports from a single module to one single import in my react project.

Example:
Convert this

```js
import { Title } from "@mantine/core";
import { Center } from "@mantine/core";
import { Divider } from "@mantine/core";
```

to

```js
import { Center, Divider, Title } from "@mantine/core";
```

Is the a eslint plugin/rule to achieve this?

Comment: What's the problem? Doesn't this just work? You don't need a plugin for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-duplicate-imports

> Disallow duplicate module imports
>
> Using a single import statement per module will make the code clearer because you can see everything being imported from that module on one line.

Try adding "no-duplicate-imports" to the rules section of your .eslintrc.* file